# Pass Mediawiki "wgUserName" to Google Tag Manager

Tags: mediawiki, google-tag-manager

I have an install of Mediawiki for my company which I have tracking page activity currently, but I also want to be able to track page activity per user.

Ideally, I'd like to pass the `wgUserName` into Google Tag Manager as the userid that Google Analytics sees.

How can I pass the `wgUserName` into the data layer from the wiki? I just need to get that into Tag Manager.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll need the data layer for this, according to https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript

You can access the config via: mw.config and the value for "wgUserName" can be found with "mw.config.get("wgUserName")"

Thus all you need to do in GTM is create a Custom JavaScript variable and reference it:
[image]

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't grab the username, it says, "undefined."

Comment: Can you try in the console and tell me if it is defined or not?

Comment: What do you mean the console? I have the GTM Debug pane open, and the tag being fired says that "userId" is "undefined."

Comment: I mean the javascript console in your browser. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Can you link to the wiki?

Comment: Wiki link: http://tcoi.co. Since you don't have a login, the expected output should be "null."

When I try: "mw.user.getName()" in the F12 console I get the desired output, but when I use a JS variable like you have in the image above, it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Matthew, changed my answer, use a Custom JavaScript variable instead.

Comment: Bless you good sir. I've been banging my head against the wall for a few hours trying to get this working.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!